# Cant accesss OpenSSL eNULL ciphers in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

For my current Project I need to communicate with a mosquito MQTT broker via TLS. The communication must be authenticated via a certificate and not encrypted. For that usecase there are available ciphers in openSSL for no authentication = `aNULL` and for no encryption `eNULL` I should use `NULL-SHA256` with is clasified as `eNULL`. You can check the available ones like this:

```
openssl ciphers  eNULL
```

for me the result is:

```
ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA:GOST2012256-NULL-STREEBOG256:GOST2001-NULL-GOST94:AECDH-NULL-SHA:NULL-SHA256:NULL-SHA:NULL-MD5
```

In PHP you can check the available ciphers by calling `openssl_get_cipher_methods()`
my result array looks kind of similar to the one described at [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-get-cipher-methods.php)
containing 144 strings.

```
 array:144 [
  0 => "aes-128-cbc"
  1 => "aes-128-cbc-hmac-sha1"
  2 => "aes-128-ccm"     
  ...
  141 => "sm4-ctr"
  142 => "sm4-ecb"
  143 => "sm4-ofb"
  ]
```

But there are no NULL ciphers available. I tried to overwrite them in the request that is send to the server

```
stream_context_create([
"ssl" => [
      "ciphers" => "ECDHE-RSA-NULL-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-NULL-SHA:AECDH-NULL-SHA:NULL-SHA256:NULL-SHA:NULL-MD5",
      ...
   ],
]
```

but looking in to wireshark:
[wiresharc request tls cipers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zINti.png)
the options are ignored and some other 4 cipers are send.

I researched the php documentation and some onle forums to get this:
in the used php build the `--with-system-ciphers` flag must be used, to allow for php to use the ciphers that openSLL on the host system provides. I looked in to available docker builds with that configuaration and found that the alpine-linux php [package](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/v3.12/community/x86_64/php7) uses that flag [on line 349](https://git.alpinelinux.org/aports/tree/community/php7/APKBUILD?id=882c869d81875be9a9ea9f6195c3a18274211397)

Executing my php script inside the container gave me 133 ciphers as result for `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` without any NULL ciphers.

I [found](https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/openssl_ciphers.1.asp) that the `ALL` option for openSSL ciphers explisitly doesn't include the eNULL ciphers.  This makes me belive that PHP cant access those NULL ciphers as there is no parameter for `openssl_get_cipher_methods()` to specify that i want NULL ciphers and not `ALL`.

Is there any knowledge about this problem on SE? How can i change the available ciphers in PHP to cantain NULL cipers? Is there a different way to connect to MQTT in PHP?

**EDIT:**
As People reply with comments that trying to do what i do is stupid, please be aware that **I am aware of that.** It is my job and i can assure you that i want and need that. The Server expects me to do that and the networke is secure.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that explicitly doesn't want encryption?

Comment: The client and server must both agree on a ciphersuite. Most servers will **not** accept ciphersuites with no encryption, even if you manage to configure the client to offer them.

Comment: It is a request from my customer for the project. everything is secure and the server expects me to do that.

Comment: ok, so you know for a fact that the server will accept such a ciphersuite. If you're not sure, you can use the tool at ssllabs.com to find out.

Comment: Yes, @President James K. Polk  That was not my Question. But thank you.

Comment: I'll admit that I'm not the best when it comes to Docker or custom PHP building, but the OpenSSL that your package is built with appears to come from [php7-openssl which has its own configuration rules](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/contents?branch=edge&name=php7-openssl&arch=x86&repo=community) for OpenSSL, which might not match your system's OpenSSL config.

Comment: No it is the [official php fpm alpine image](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/3dc9a6988d478fae0f0b8b871d10e611b50e3d0c/7.4/alpine3.12/cli/Dockerfile):
inside the container i can see the eNULL ciphers  using `openssl ciphers  eNULL `

Comment: So in that link, what appears to be the build script doesn't include the `with-system-ciphers` option. Can you grep your php-info to see if it includes the actual build command. Ubuntu removed it from info, but I think Alpine might have it still. Even better, if `php7-dev` is installed, you can run `php-config --configure-options | grep cipher` to see if it is listed.

Comment: And I understand that your CLI is saying one thing, I'm just saying that the CLI version of OpenSSL isn't necessarily the same as the PHP version.

Comment: @ChrisHaas thank you! I tried to build my own container using the linked script and manually added the flag. i could see it in the availabla php-config options like you sugested, but i still cant change the available ciphers in php.

Comment: Well that's good to know, thank you for trying those steps at least. If no one here has the answer, you might want to also post to the office [PHP mailing lists](https://news-web.php.net/php.general), you might get a response there. Good luck!

Comment: did that before posting here...^^